# Unable to restart mongod

Tags: networking, configuration, ssl, mongodb

I have edited the `/etc/mongodb.conf` file by adding ssl tag.

```
net:
 port: 27017
 bindIp: [127.0.0.1]
 ssl:
  mode: requireSSL
  PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem`
```

However I have not edited the rest of the file. The `.pem` file is in the correct path. And yet after editing and restart `mongod`, it is not starting up. Can someone point me out the error in my config file? I have followed the steps using the following link [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/)

Comment: Have you checked your `mongod` logs for startup errors? Is this a self-signed certificate?

Comment: `2017-03-01T04:44:08.857+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2017-03-01T04:44:08.859+0000 E NETWORK  [main] cannot read PEM key file: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem error:0906406D:PEM routines:PEM_def_callback:problems getting password
2017-03-01T04:44:08.859+0000 F CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: InvalidSSLConfiguration: Can not set up PEM key file`. This is the log entry once in restart mongod

Answer (score 1):

The error would suggest that you have encrypted the PEM file and it hence requires a passphrase to be used (and is not getting it). You can use such certs with MongoDB, but you have to decide how you [pass in the passphrase](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/#ssl-certificate-passphrase) - you can do it via the command line, the config file or by being prompted (though that requires an interactive startup of course). Alternatively you can remove the password from the PEM file with a command something like:

`openssl rsa -in /etc/ssl/private/example.key -out /etc/ssl/private/example.nocrypt.key`

You will be prompted for the passphrase at this point, and then the output file will have no passphrase.